# Vue3 with Typescript -> this object is possibly undefined

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

Every time I use the "this" keyword in my code, it highlights and says that "Object is possibly undefined

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you define the data property as an arrow function you should pass `this` as parameter like:

```
data:(vm)=>{//vm represents this keyword
   return{
      ....
      productType:vm.$route.path.slice(1).split("/")[0]
  }
}
```